# Reference for a "wild" problem

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, representation-theory

I am currently working on something related to the character theory of the group of unipotent upper triangular matrices with elements in a finite field.  I have seen in many papers on the topic the statement that determining the irreducible characters and conjugacy classes of these groups is a "wild" problem, but never with a proof or any additional information as to what this might mean.  I have asked the professor that I am working with, and he didn't know the precise statement of this property either, only that it meant that it was impossible to solve (in some sense).

Seeing as how I have been unable to find any information about this on the internet, I am wondering if anyone could either explain it to me, or point me to a useful source.  Thanks!

Here is an example paper that shows what I am talking about:
http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~cgates/PERSI/papers/PatternGroups_1.pdf

---

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The precise definition is discussed at [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/10481/when-is-a-classification-problem-wild). A classification problem is said to be wild if it contains the classification of representations of $F_2$ (equivalently, the classification of a pair of linear operators up to simultaneous conjugation) as a subproblem.

One reason for this to be a reasonable definition: there is a remarkable [theorem of Drozd](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/5895/what-are-tame-and-wild-hereditary-algebras) which asserts that the representation theory of a finite-dimensional algebra is either wild or, for fixed dimension $d$, the indecomposable $d$-dimensional representations decompose into a finite number of $1$-parameter families with finitely many exceptions. And as Mariano says in the linked question,

> One of the reasons that make this theorem so amazing is that one can show that if $A$ is wild then $\text{mod}_A$ contains copies of the module categories of *all* finite dimensional algebras; in other words, wild algebras are really wild...

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you for your exposition as well.  I find it amusing that I originally thought the same thing as the asker in the MO question, that the word wild was simply a colorful name for a problem the author found particularly exciting or difficult.  Of course, when I saw it used by different authors in multiple papers, I began to suspect otherwise...

Answer (score 7):

In linear algebra, a "wild" problem is one that contains the problem of classifying pairs of (noncommuting) matrices up to simultaneous similarity.  Problems of this type are considered to be virtually hopeless.  See [this arXiv paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/0709.2488) for more information.