# Are all matrix groups (Lie groups) known

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, group-theory

Just wondering if there are any matrix groups out there waiting to be discovered, or if they are all known?

Comment: I think the [classification of finite-dimensional Lie algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semisimple_Lie_algebra#Classification) is close to an answer for your question.

Comment: This is a cool question. How can you prove that you found all subgroups of a group?

Comment: To be clear, [this link referenced by @RobArthan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semisimple_Lie_algebra#Classification) is for simple and semisimple finite dimensional Lie algebras. There is quite a beastly collection of nonsemisimple finite dimensional Lie algebras.

Comment: @LeeMosher: agreed: that's why I said "close to an answer" as I didn't really know what the OP was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no known classification of finite-dimensional real Lie algebras. Since any such Lie algebra is the Lie algebra of some matrix group, the answer to your question is negative.

Comment: Has anyone attempted to classify the lie groups directly? Or is it considered more manageable to approach it via the lie algebras?

Comment: It is considered more manageable to approach it via Lie algebras, since the same Lie algebra can be the Lie algebra of several non-isomorphic Lie groups. And also because the classification of the Lie algebras is basically a problem concerning finite-dimensional vector spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the classification of nilpotent Lie algebras, even over the complex numbers, is only known up to dimension $7$. In dimension $8$, there are only partial results. So it is clear that the classification is a [wild problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/43280/reference-for-a-wild-problem).

References:

This [MO-question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/21114/low-dimensional-nilpotent-lie-algebras),

[Classification results for solvable lie algebras.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2178279/classification-results-for-solvable-lie-algebras)